# Change value of input box based on selected item and other value

Tags: javascript

So basically, I am creating an application form for gym membership. 
The base cost is $100. If juggling is selected, the cost will increase by $50. 
Also, the base cost will increase by $50 if the 'BMI' is > 25 and <= 30. If the 'BMI' is > 30, it will increase by $100 instead. 
This is my code. It is not working as intended. Would like some help. Thanks a lot.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>UWS application form</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Prac1Task2.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
    <form>
    <fieldset>
    <legend>Fitness Details</legend>
Favourite Activities: <br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="activity" value="cycling" id="cycling"><label for="cycling">Cycling</label>    
    <input type="checkbox" name="activity" value="50" id="juggling" onchange="update(this);"><label for="juggling">Juggling</label>     
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <label for="height">What is your height &#40;Meters&#41;</label><br/>
    <input type="number" name="height" id="height" class="input" onchange="getBMI()">
    <br/>
    <label for="weight">What is your weight? &#40;kg&#41;</label><br/>
    <input type="number" name="weight" id="weight" class="input" onchange="getBMI()">
    <br/>
    <label for="bmi">BMI:</label><br/>
    <input type="number" name="bmi" id="bmi" class="input" value="" readonly>
    <script>
        function getBMI()
        {
            var height = document.getElementById("height").value;
            var weight = document.getElementById("weight").value;
            document.getElementById("bmi").value = (weight / height) / height;
            var bmi = document.getElementById("bmi");
            var price = document.getElementById("price").value;
            if (bmi.value > 25 && bmi.value <= 30)
            {

                parseInt(price.value) += parseInt(50);
            document.getElementById('price').value =  price.value;
            }
            else if (bmi.value > 30)
            {
                document.getElementById("price").value = document.getElementById("price").value + 100;

            }
    }
    </script>

    </fieldset>
    <br/>
    <fieldset>
    <legend>Application Details</legend>
    Date of Application:<br/>
    <input class="input" id="date" name="date" readonly />
    <script>
    var timetime = new Date();
    document.getElementById("date").value = (timetime.getDate() + "/" + (timetime.getMonth() + 1)
                + "/" + timetime.getFullYear());
    </script>
<br/><br/>
Cost of Application: <br/>
$<input type="number" class="input" id="price" name="price" step="0.01" value="100" readonly />
    <script>
    var total = 100;
    function update(feature) {

        if(feature.checked == true){

            total += parseInt(feature.value);
        document.getElementById('price').value =  total;
        }

        if(feature.checked == false){

            total -= parseInt(feature.value);
            document.getElementById('price').value =  total;
            }
    }
    </script>
    </fieldset>
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="button">
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Unless your gym members can only be either 1 or 2 meters high, I’d suggest adding a `step="0.01"` to your “height” field as well.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't mentioned the exact issue which you are facing. However, I think there should be some problem with this line of code.

```
 parseInt(price.value) += parseInt(50);
```

parseInt() is a function and you cannot assign values to it.

It should be some thing like this

```
price.value = parseInt(price.value) + parseInt(50);
```

Also price.value is not a proper reference because you are assigning `document.getElementById("price").value;` to it. So you should be using *price* instead of *price.value*

Comment: when a BMI is calculated. the total becomes $10050 instead of $150

Comment: 100+50 = 10050 ...this will happen if you don't properly typecast you variables

Comment: If you are not sure about whats happening inside the code use alerts on each step of the calculation and figure out where exactly the problem is

Comment: tried price.value = parseInt(price.value) + parseInt(50);. now the total input box goes blank

Comment: As I mentioned in the answer use price instead of price.value

Comment: price = parseInt(price.value) + parseInt(50); like this ?